# .NET: &function_name syntax

Tags: .net, delegates, c++-cli

What does the syntax `&function_name` mean?

For example, as used in the delegate

```
System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::DoWorkEvent)
```

as used with event handling with a `BackgroundWorker` object.

The delegate prototype is

```
public delegate void DoWorkEventHandler(Object^ sender, DoWorkEventArgs^ e)
```

Presumably this means that `&Form1::DoWorkEvent` returns a `DoWorkEventArgs` object? But that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Why tag something `c#` if it's clearly about syntax unique to C++/CLI?

Comment: The concept appears similar (at least at a quick glance) to that in C# so I thought I'd tag it to get C# programmers' input. If the concepts are different, I'm sorry.

Comment: You're asking about specific syntax though, not the underlying concept. And the syntax *is* different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::DoWorkEvent)` *creates* a delegate. The syntax for creating a delegate is `gcnew delegatename(thisObject, functionPointer)`. It creates a delegate that calls `functionPointer` with `this` set to `thisObject`.

To *invoke* a delegate, you call it with the appropriate parameters. `delegateVariable->Invoke(parameter1, parameter2, etc)`. In the case of `DoWorkEventHandler`, `parameter1` is `sender` and `parameter2` is `e`.

You're confusing two different things, creation and invocation. The line `DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::DoWorkEvent)` creates a delegate. The two parameters are `thisObject` and `functionPointer`, not `sender` and `e`.

This should have been covered by whatever book/resource you used to learn about delegates in the first place. For example, [this article](http://drdobbs.com/184401980) says

> Creating a delegate instance involves calling a constructor. If you
>   are encapsulating a static function, you pass in one argument, a
>   pointer to that member function. For an instance function, you must
>   pass in two arguments: a handle to that instance, as well a pointer to
>   the instance member function.

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is quite rusty but I don't think you're looking at .NET at all, but a standard C++ member-function pointer.